# .pos_ in SpaCy is not returning any results in Python

Tags: python, spacy

I'm really new to programming and python and I've been trying to use SpaCy in my python 3.x. However, when I try to apply .pos_ to a text to find the part of speech I do not get any result for part of speech. I've made sure that SpaCy is properly installed and have browsed other Stackoverflow posts and this [one](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1016) github post however it did not help.

Here is the code that I used:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
parser = English()

tokens = parser('She ran')
dir(tokens[0])
print(dir(tokens[0]))


def show_POS(text):
    tokens = parser(text)
    for token in tokens:
       print(token.text, token.pos_)


show_POS("She hit the wall.")


def show_dep(text):
    tokens = parser(text)
    for token in tokens:
        print(" {} : {} : {} :{}".format(token.orth_,token.pos_,token.dep_,token.head))


print("token : POS : dep. : head")
print("-------------------------")
show_dep("She hit the wall.")

ex1 = parser("he drinks a water")
for word in ex1:
print(word.text,word.pos_)
```

---

And here is the output:

```
/Users/dalals4/PycharmProjects/NLP-LEARNING/venv/bin/python 
/Users/dalals4/PycharmProjects/NLP_learning_practice_chp5.py
['_', '__bytes__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', 
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__len__', 
'__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__pyx_vtable__', '__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', 
'ancestors', 'check_flag', 'children', 'cluster', 'conjuncts', 'dep', 
'dep_', 'doc', 'ent_id', 'ent_id_', 'ent_iob', 'ent_iob_', 'ent_type', 
'ent_type_', 'get_extension', 'has_extension', 'has_vector', 'head', 
'i', 'idx', 'is_alpha', 'is_ancestor', 'is_ascii', 'is_bracket', 
'is_currency', 'is_digit', 'is_left_punct', 'is_lower', 'is_oov', 
'is_punct', 'is_quote', 'is_right_punct', 'is_sent_start', 'is_space', 
'is_stop', 'is_title', 'is_upper', 'lang', 'lang_', 'left_edge', 
'lefts', 'lemma', 'lemma_', 'lex_id', 'like_email', 'like_num', 
'like_url', 'lower', 'lower_', 'n_lefts', 'n_rights', 'nbor', 'norm', 
'norm_', 'orth', 'orth_', 'pos', 'pos_', 'prefix', 'prefix_', 'prob', 
'rank', 'right_edge', 'rights', 'sent_start', 'sentiment', 
'set_extension', 'shape', 'shape_', 'similarity', 'string', 'subtree', 
'suffix', 'suffix_', 'tag', 'tag_', 'text', 'text_with_ws', 'vector', 
'vector_norm', 'vocab', 'whitespace_']
She 
hit 
the 
wall 
. 
token : POS : dep. : head
-------------------------
 She :  :  : She
 hit :  :  : hit
 the :  :  : the
 wall :  :  : wall
 . :  :  : .
he 
drinks 
a 
water 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're only importing the English *language class*, which includes the language-specific data like tokenization rules. But you're not actually loading in a *model*, which enables spaCy to predict part-of-speech tags and other linguistic annotations.

If you haven't done so already, you first need to [installed a model package](https://spacy.io/usage/models), e.g. the small English model:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

You can then tell spaCy to load it by calling `spacy.load`:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u"she ran")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_)
```

This will give you an instance of the `English` class with the model weights loaded in, so spaCy can predict part-of-speech tags, dependency labels and named entities.

If you're new to spaCy, I'd recommend checking out [the spaCy 101 guide](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#annotations-pos-deps) in the docs. It explains the most important concepts, and includes many examples that you can run.